# protoc custom plugin erroring out with Program not found or is not executable

Tags: java, protoc, protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

I am trying to build a custom protoc plugin to generate custom output from .proto files. I literally copied java file containing CodeGenerator from [protoc custom plugin](https://github.com/thesamet/protoc-plugin-in-java) as a starting point and renamed it. I also followed [executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52824549/dependencies-for-protoc-java-plugin) and created .sh file. The content of my shell script is as follows.

[image: example.sh]

I also add the PATH variable value and output of the plugin execution. Can someone point me where I am going wrong with this? The shell script runs fine separately executing the main method

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If that is your entire `example.sh`, it won't work because it doesn't have a "hashbang" line identifying the script interpreter.

It should be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
java cp ...
```

I think that's likely your problem because I tried running `protoc` and specifying an plug-in in the same way you did, and it worked as long as the plug-in was actually executable on its own.

Answer (score 1):

The `protoc` error messaging is a little cryptic here. You have 3 options for providing a plugin to `protoc`:

1. A plugin in your `$PATH` following the `protoc-gen-$NAME` format. This will be automatically picked up.
2. A plugin *not* conforming to the above naming convention, but available in your `$PATH`. This can be executed with the `--plugin=$some-nonconventional-name`.
3. A plugin not in your `$PATH`. This requires suppling an absolute path or relative path (from the current working directory) to the executable. This is executed with `--plugin=proto-gen-$any-name-you-want=$path-to-executable`

Expanding on 3 above. If you create a file `example-plugin`:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Example Plugin Running!"
```

You'll then want to make sure it's executable:

```
chmod +x ./example-plugin
```

We need an output directory, let's make one:

```
mdkir plugin-output
```

We need a `.proto` file. Find one and name it anything you like, like `MyProto.proto`

Let's pick an arbitrary name for this plugin. We can call it `foo`.

Then you'll execute it with `protoc` as follows:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-foo=$PATH_TO_EXAMPLE_PLUGIN --foo_output=./plugin-output  MyProto.proto
```

You should see something like:

```
--foo_out: protoc-gen-foo: Plugin output is unparseable: Example Plugin Running!\n
```

Answer (score 0):

how about using absolute path of example.sh? protoc working directory may not be current folder.