# Problem with Custom protobuf CodeGenerator

Tags: java, protoc, protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

I am undergoing trouble writing the custom protoc plugin. I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62168625/protoc-custom-plugin-erroring-out-with-program-not-found-or-is-not-executable) but no response. Atleast Kindly please let me know answers to few questions. I really need to do this. I havent gone past first step itself.

1. From this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432876/how-to-write-a-custom-protobuf-codegenerator-in-java), how do they link shell script with plugin name protoc-gen-code.

   java -cp ./codegen.jar CodeGeneratorMain "$@"
2. With respect to the above implementation in the question and google proto buffer documentation, what exactly would be there in the path.. is it the path of the Shell Script? would the shell script be named as protoc-gen-code?

Can someone please respond to these queries.

Answer (score 0):

`protoc` can generate code for several different languages with one invocation. The way you specify which languages you want is to use the command line arguments of the form `--LANG_out` where `LANG` is the language you want. So `--cpp_out` gives you C++ code, directory, `--js_out` gives you JavaScript etc. If `protoc` doesn't recognize `LANG` then it looks for a plugin called `protoc-gen-LANG` and uses it as the code generator.

The shell script can be called whatever. Let's say you call it `mygen.sh` and you decide you want to use `mylang` as LANG. Then the `protoc` invocation looks like:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-mylang=/path/to/mygen.sh --mylang_out=/some/dir some.proto
```